# Disable automatic archive generation for executable target in CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, build

I have a C++ project that I want to build using CMake with `Makefile Generators`. I created a simple `CMakeLists` that only contains executable and directory configuration. The project was built and run successfully.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(proj)

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)

add_executable(proj
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/catch2/catch.cpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/test.cpp
)
```

The linking process generates an archive file under the executable target folder `CMakeFiles/proj.dir`. The auto-generated `link.txt` file that is used in the link process contains these lines.

```
"cmake.exe" -E rm -f CMakeFiles\proj.dir/objects.a
ar.exe cr CMakeFiles\proj.dir/objects.a @CMakeFiles\proj.dir\objects1.rsp
g++.exe -g   -Wl,--whole-archive CMakeFiles\proj.dir/objects.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive  -o ..\bin\proj.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libproj.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0 @CMakeFiles\proj.dir\linklibs.rsp
```

As far as I understand, by default CMake generates an archive and then creates an executable from that archive. Is there a way to simplify this step? I just want to link objects as an executable not generate an additional archive file. The expected `link.txt` file should be like that:

```
g++.exe -g -o ..\bin\proj.exe @CMakeFiles\proj.dir\objects1.rsp
```

Comment: @Tsyvarev I'm sorry my original post was not clear enough. CMake generates an `objects.a` under the target folder along with the executable. I just want to discard that static library generation.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thank you for your feedback. I've edited the question. I hope it is clearer this time.

Comment: Yes, in the new form the question becomes pretty clear.