How can I configure the linker in CMake so that it uses g++ instead of ar + c++?
My problem is, that I want to use lld as dropin linker in my mingw installation. So I've copied the lld.exe as lld.exe, ld.lld.exe and lld-link.exe to my mingw bin directory (only one of them is really needed, but which one, is a little bit unclear - but this is not my question here).
When I compile manually, I use g++ to convert a .cpp file into a .o file.
When I link manually, I use g++ to convert my .o files into .exe, I also add the "-fuse-ld=lld" to this call.
With that the compilation tooks some minutes (many files) and the linking only 2-3 sec (instead of minutes using the standard ld.exe).

Now CMake: when I do the same with CMake, I first had the problem, that whatever I did, the linker is not using the lld. I tried everything that you can find in internet regarding this. I end up to setting
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-fuse-ld=lld")
this results in the "lld" setting added also to the linking command in the link.txt file, that is generated by cmake in the build directory:
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E rm -f CMakeFiles\UnitTests.dir/objects.a C:\Tools\mingw64\bin\ar.exe qc CMakeFiles\UnitTests.dir/objects.a @CMakeFiles\UnitTests.dir\objects1.rsp C:\Tools\mingw64\bin\c++.exe -fuse-ld=lld -g -O1 -Wl,--whole-archive CMakeFiles\UnitTests.dir/objects.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive -o ..\bin\UnitTests.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libUnitTests.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,1,--minor-image-version,0 @CMakeFiles\UnitTests.dir\linkLibs.rsp 
This works, but the problem is as you see, this are 3 commands: 1) rm which is fast, 2) ar.exe which is slow, 3) c++ linker call, which is again fast. So all of the .o files are in the list "objects.a" that are provided to the "ar.exe" command. Then the linker takes it as an archive and creates the binary.
When I replace that by this here:
C:\Tools\mingw64\bin\g++.exe -fuse-ld=lld -g -O1 @CMakeFiles\UnitTests.dir\objects1.rsp -o ..\bin\UnitTests.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libUnitTests.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,1,--minor-image-version,0 @CMakeFiles\UnitTests.dir\linkLibs.rsp
The linking is again very fast, as I skip the ar.exe. I don't see and disadvantages.

Now my question: how can I configure my CMake, so it uses "g++" and provides the .o files to it directly, instead of going over ar.exe. This is for me unclear.
I didn't found any information about, what I can change. Also I didn't try too much, because I really don't know where to start. Honestly I am user of CMake since yesterday :D So dont blame me of my missing knowledge. I hope to find a solution here.

-DCMAKE_AR=llvm-ar should make it use llvm-ar, which should be faster than the regular ar.

Also you shouldn't need to manually modify your compiler installation, just add LLD to PATH.

CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS is for the C++ compiler flags. Use target_link_options to set options and flags for the linker.

After writing this, I found a duplicate question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72325029/disable-automatic-archive-generation-for-executable-target-in-cmake

target_link_options seams not to work for me - the normal ld.exe is used and the linking takes minutes

On an unrelated note, don't just copy files to the MinGW binary directory. First see if there's a LLVM package for MinGW to be installed, and if there isn't then add the LLVM binary installation directory to your PATH.

How about the CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_LINKER variable? And CMAKE_AR for ar?

add_link_options("-fuse-ld=lld")?

All what you proposed I've tried and nothing helped me. The call to the archiver before linking is hardcoded in CMake (see my answer with the solution I created).

I found an answer to this while investigating the sources of CMake. This is my soulution (it can be, this does not work for your projects, but it helps me a lot).
So I checked in the sources, how the link.txt is done. Then I followed the commands and found this file:
https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/master/Modules/CMakeCXXInformation.cmake
Using this I played a little bit and found out, that this helps me:
For projects creating a shared library I used this:
set(CMAKE_CXX_CREATE_SHARED_LIBRARY "<CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER> <CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_CXX_FLAGS> <LANGUAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS> <LINK_FLAGS> <CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_CREATE_CXX_FLAGS> <SONAME_FLAG><TARGET_SONAME> -o <TARGET> <OBJECTS>")

For projects creating an executable I used this:
set(CMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE "<CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER> <FLAGS> <CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS> <LINK_FLAGS> <OBJECTS> -o <TARGET>")

Both lines are just copy&paste from https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/master/Modules/CMakeCXXInformation.cmake and the definitions on the end of the file. It seams, that defining this variables prevents the creation of the additional archive files.
I think, the archive files were used to be able to link a huge amount of .o files, where then they are splitted into multiple archive-commands. The linker then get the whole archive instead of each object file on its own. The limitation is possibily the command line length. But for my project this works fine and currently I don't have any issues.
Edit:
I've found a small problem: the executable-project linker searches for libMylib.dll.a, which is not more present. So I needed first to delete the <LINK_LIBRARIES> part from the above "set" commands. Then provide the -L option pointing to my build directory and also the -lMyLib option, both as executable-project compiler options. Currently I'm not using any external libraries, but I need that in future, so also for them I would need to specify -L and -l. This is OK for me, as long as the linker execution in Cmake is not improved natively.
